# Synthetic data for PCA

Tags: pca, synthetic-data

I was trying to evaluate different algorithms for PCA like eigenvalue decomposition, SVD, Lanczos Algorithm, Power iteration.
I also want to do some other analysis

I could find any papers concerning this.
What would be the best method to generate synthetic for PCA.
Basically generate data with "principal components" and noise and find which method finds it optimally.
Any reference would be appreciated.

Edit :
The goal is to find if PCs calculated from EVD are "better" than PCs caculated from other methods. Or in general which method works best in identifying PCS.
I was thinking of generating synthetic PCs first then convert them to singular features and then apply each algorithm, but i am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Since PCA is not a model, you don't really have a way for generating data. You have to supply a model in order to generate data from it. Something like "probabilistic PCA" may be a good start.

Comment: @utobi Could you point me to some resources for generating synthetic data for probabilistic pca?

Comment: Based on the limited information you give, create any arbitrary matrix of numbers whatsoever and apply PCA to it.  In order to determine a "best" method, we need some way to assess whether one method is better than another.  Either you must specify that quantitatively or give us enough information about your context and objectives to be able to propose a suitable method.